# Eliminating spaces between Textboxes

Tags: php, forms, textbox

I have something like this :

```
$form->addElement(new Element\Textbox("M_89 :",$M_89,array("onchange"=> "this.form.submit()","value"=> $M_89)));
$form->addElement(new Element\Textbox("M_90 :",$M_90,array("onchange"=> "this.form.submit()","value"=> $M_90)));
```

And it has space between those buttons. I want the buttons side by side. How can I do that? Is there a way without HTML?

```
HTML code?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .sidebar-nav {
        padding: 9px 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Are we taking about that each button is on each their line or?

Comment: Yes they are on different lines and I want to put them in the same line.

Comment: Could you show the html? But most likely you'll be able to solve with with css, try something like: `display:inline;` or perhaps `display:inline-bock;`

Comment: I didn't write code in html,I wrote it in PHP. Is something like http://www.imavex.com/pfbc3.x-php5/examples/validation.php

Comment: Yes, but when you see the page you can inspect the content and paste the html code in, None the less, the css should still do the trick,

Comment: Is this the code? I have a longer code at the end of the page,but it is about the buttons and the data that must fill the textboxes and the select elements.